# Nested comments with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently trying to replicate something similar to a forum, but I'm stumped on how I could create nested comments. I understand that for regular replies I could create a replies table and run a loop for each comment that matches the thread id. But I don't know how I would easily do this for nested replies.

Could someone please give me some advice or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

This is the structure for my posts table:

[Screenshot of phpMyAdmin http://bitdrops.co/drops/J5v.png](http://bitdrops.co/drops/J5v.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you curious how to set up the relationships on the model, or everything? If you could post your source code on any attempts you have made.

Comment: I can't tell if you are using the words comments and replies interchangeably or if they are two different things in two different tables.

Comment: @whoacowboy Yes, I'm trying to set up the entire comment system. I had this idea though, so tell me how practical this is: Create a comments table with id, user id, post id, is_nested_reply, comment. And then in my view I loop through the table and if is_nested reply = true then it places the comment under the reply. I'm not sure how well I'm articulating myself, it seemed to make more sense in my head lol. and yes i am using them interchangeably

Comment: How do you plan to hold the nesting in the database? The simple way is for each comment to have a `reply_to` FK to point to another comment (or null for top comment). However this tends to get expensive at deep levels of nesting - look into "nested set" solutions instead. There's loads for PHP on the web, but search for Laravel as well, as someone may already have done this.

Comment: (When showing your schema, the text output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts` is much more readable, by the way, as well as having better accessibility and SEO).

Comment: @halfer It's not just SEO. It means you can cut and paste the text, and it helps people who need a screen-reader because of vision problems. Then again, I have pretty good vision and that screenshot is barely legible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to look into [polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) to solve this. You want to be able to comment on Posts and Comments.

What I have done is set up a commentable [trait](http://culttt.com/2014/06/25/php-traits/) and have the models I want to add comments to use it. This way if you ever want to comment on another model, you can just add the trait to that model.

Laracasts is a great resource for laravel and [has a good lesson on traits](https://laracasts.com/lessons/whats-a-trait).

There is a bit more to it than this, but hopefully it will get you started.

You set up your database structure like this.

**User Table**

```
  `id` int(10),
  `name` varchar(255),
  `username` varchar(255)
```

**Comments table**

```
  `id` int(10),
  `user_id` int(10),
  `body` text,
  `commentable_id` int(10),
  `commentable_type` varchar(255)
```

**Posts Table**

```
  `id` int(10),
  `user_id` int(10),
  `body` text
```

Your models like this.

**Comment Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model {

    use CommentableTrait;

    /**
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**Post Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use CommentableTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

    use CommentableTrait;

}
```

and of course you need the trait.

**Trait**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Comment;

trait CommentableTrait {

    /**
     * List of users who have favorited this item
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comments\Comment', 'commentable')->latest();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function addComment($body, $user_id)
    {

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->body = $body;
        $comment->user_id = $user_id;

        $this->comments()->save($comment);

        return $comment;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you need a `post_id` on the `comments` table to associate comments with posts? What about threaded comments, can you show us an example of that? @whoacowboy

Comment: `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` are used instead of `post_id`. `commentable_id` is the `post_id` and `commentable_type` = `App\Post`. Check out http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations . For the threaded comments please post another question and send me a link.

Comment: I've created the thread, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088333/laravel-5-how-to-do-multi-threaded-comments

Comment: Can you explain the `App\Comments\Comment`part? I don't think this namespace is valid...?

Comment: @Aborted Typically Laravel wants to put all models in the app directory. When building larger apps, sometimes it is easier to group you classes by function. I put all the classes related to comments in a Comments directory under apps that way whenever I need to do something with comments all the related classes are grouped together.

Comment: @whoacowboy Ohhh okay, got it! Thanks going through the trouble to explain :), I didn't really expect a separate directory for the comments model which led me to think that it might be a typo on your side!