# Laravel 5: how to do multi threaded comments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using [Laravel Commentable](https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable) package which uses Nested Sets pattern with [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum).

I have managed to allow users to make comments on posts but they're not threaded, each comment has `depth` set to zero in the database.

So I'm wondering how does one go about making multi threaded comments like reddit for example?

These are my tables

```
users: id, name, email...
posts: id, user_id, subreddit_id...
comments: id, body, parent_id, lft, rgt, depth, commentable_id, commentable_type, user_id
```

My Models (Comment and User)

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    use Commentable;

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

This is how I'm submitting comments in `PostsController`

```
public function createComment($id) {

    $post = Post::with('user.votes')->with('subreddit.moderators')->where('id', $id)->first();

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = Input::get('comment');
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();

    $post->comments()->save($comment);
}
```

And this is the view

```
    <div class="post-comments">

    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['comment', $post]]) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Your Comment</label>
            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}

    <div class="comments-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    there are {{ count($comments) }} comments <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Best</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hot</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="media">
            <!-- first comment -->
            @foreach($comments as $comment)
            <div class="media-heading">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $comment->id }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button> <span class="label label-info">12314</span> {{ $comment->user->name }} 12 hours ago
            </div>

            <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="{{ $comment->id }}">

                <div class="media-left">
                    <div class="vote-wrap">
                        <div class="vote up">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vote inactive">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- vote-wrap -->
                </div>
                <!-- media-left -->


                <div class="media-body">
                    <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                    <div class="comment-meta">
                        <span><a href="#">delete</a></span>
                        <span><a href="#">report</a></span>
                        <span><a href="#">hide</a></span>
          <span>
                    <a class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#replyCommentT" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">reply</a>
                  </span>
                        <div class="collapse" id="replyCommentT">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="comment">Your Comment</label>
                                    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- comment-meta -->

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- comments -->
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <!-- first comment -->

    </div>

</div>
<!-- post-comments -->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used [Laravel Commentable](https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable) package, but the [docs](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#creating-root-node) look pretty good.

I believe you need `use Commentable;` on your `Post` model and not your `Comment` model.

It looks like your `Comment` model needs to extend `Baum\Node` and not `Model`

Then what you have should work.

```
$post = Post::with('user.votes')->with('subreddit.moderators')->where('id', $id)->first();

$comment = new Comment;
$comment->body = Input::get('comment');
$comment->user_id = Auth::id();

$post->comments()->save($comment);

// or you could do 

$comment->makeChildOf($post);
```

To make a comment on a comment, it looks like you do something like this. I would probably make a CommentsController.

```
public function addComment(Request $request){
    $parent = Comment::find(Input::get('parent_id'));

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = Input::get('comment');
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();

    $comment->makeChildOf($parent);
}
```

The [Relations](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#relations), [Root and Leaf scopes](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#root-and-leaf-scopes), [Accessing the ancestry/descendancy chain](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#accessing-the-ancestrydescendancy-chain) section of the docs have several examples on how to then retrieve the comments for comments.

**Edit**

It looks like the [Comment](https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable/blob/2.0/src/Commentable/Comment.php) model in the package already extends the Baum\Node so you don't need to do that. In order to use this package, it looks like you need to use his [Comment](https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable/blob/2.0/src/Commentable/Comment.php) model. I am sure you could use his model as a base and roll your own.

You could do something like this. You would have to set up a route.

```
<div class="collapse" id="replyCommentT">    

    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['comment', $comment]]) !!}

        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comment->id }}"/>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="comment">Your Comment</label>

            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>

    {!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
```

Comment: The package I'm using says nothing about extending `Baum\Node` are you sure I should do that? I am already importing `Commentable` into `Post` model. A quick question regarding `parent_id` - should I create a hidden input with `$comment->id` as a value?

Comment: @Halnex A the bottom of https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable he links to https://github.com/etrepat/baum#model-configuration where it talks about it. Also try it out and see if it works.

Comment: @Halnex Apparently the `Comment` model already extends Node. https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable/blob/2.0/src/Commentable/Comment.php

Comment: so I don't need to create my own `Comment` model? I just extended `Baum` and commenting still works. I'm still confused on how to retrieve `parent_id` from the view. Should I do it with a hidden input with `$comment->id` as a value?

Comment: Is it ok if I posted my html so you could tell me exactly where I need to place `parent_id` ?

Comment: Post away. As I mentioned, I have never worked with this package, so anything I am advising is my best guess.

Comment: I understand. This is my first time doing something like this too, whatever help you could give is much appreciated. I have updated my original post. In my view, I have the default textarea field where comments will be parent by default, but if you click "reply" link, it will load a comment box under that comment. Maybe I should place it there?

Comment: thank you, I will try this in an hour after dinner. So from what you're telling me, I can just remove the `Comment` model I created because by default it will use the one that came with the package?

Comment: @Halnex you *have* to use theirs. It won't work with yours, as the Commentable trait returns their class, not your custom one.

Comment: @whoacowboy I followed your instructions, but when I submit a reply to a comment, I'm getting the following error `MoveNotPossibleException in Move.php line 198: A new node cannot be moved.`

Comment: @whoacowboy it's working. I had to `$comment->save()` before I move it as a child node. But unfortunately, `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` are not being submitted.

Comment: @whoacowboy it's not fully working, `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` are not being inserted when I reply to a comment. it's weird, I'm just saving before `makeChildOf`

Comment: Wait, is this how it's supposed to behave? When it's a reply to a comment with `parent_id` it doesn't include `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` ?

Comment: @Halnex I would go through the plugin and read the source code. Look at the `makeChildOf` and `save` methods and see what they are doing. It should tell you what fields you need. Good luck!

Comment: @whoacowboy I've been reading the documentation since yesterday. One thing I need to know, is it supposed to behave this way or not? Maybe child comments don't come with commentable values. Do you have any idea? because I don't wanna chase a ghost.