# using Laravel-Commentable

Tags: php, laravel, comments, laravel-5

I have a system of commenting models driven by the 
[Laralvel-Commentable](https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable) package

Unfortunately I am underskilled in PHP for the job of implementing nested comments (replies).

### Problem : adding a reply:

When I used hints from this thread: [Laravel 5: how to do multi threaded comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088333/laravel-5-how-to-do-multi-threaded-comments)

And added this code to the `create` method:

```
    $object = Lead::find($input['item_id']);
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = $input['comment'];
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
// added section
    if(isset($input['parent_id'])) {
        $comment->makeChildOf($input['parent_id']);
    }
// end of added section

    $object->comments()->save($comment);
```

Note: in the reply form I have a hidden input

```
                {!! Form::hidden('parent_id', $o->id) !!}
```

After submitting the form I get this error:

```
MoveNotPossibleException in Move.php line 198: A new node cannot be moved.
```

#### Thing to do: make the thing work properly. I have no clue! Sorry.

Comment: The package laravel-commentable is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

```
$comment->save();
```

before trying to move the new comment into a child position. So in other words you should do this:

```
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->body = $input['comment'];
$comment->user_id = Auth::id();
// Save first
$comment->save();

// added section
if(isset($input['parent_id'])) {
    $comment->makeChildOf($input['parent_id']);
}
// end of added section
```

When you save the comment object it gets an id from your database and that id is used to relate to the parent - child relationship